# Should it be expected that some shielded wire is not good at data transmission?

Tags: wire, shielding

I have recently purchased a reel of [this specification](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/multicore-industrial-cable/6600435/) screened wire from RS Components to use in I2C communications, expecting it to be very well suited to purpose. I am running at approximately 400 kHz clock on the wire and did not think for a second that the choice of cable might limit the speed I could run at. However on oscilloscope inspection, the bus signals are extremely dulled by the connection of a 3m length of this wire.

Is the problem with the I2C master not having a sufficient pullup resistor say, or is the wire genuinely at fault? Is there a significantly better wire specification I could use for this application?

**Further Information:**

It is true this wire is listed as 95pF/m. I have found a different spec of wire (for microphone use) that seems potentially impossible based on the physics discussed, but [here it is](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/22837.pdf), 55-105pF/km.

Comment: At 100pF per meter, that 300pF and 1K ohm pullup implements 0.3uS time constant to 63%, 0.6uS to 90%.

Comment: I2C is not designed to be run over long lengths of wire like that. It is designed for connecting chips on a PCB (or at worst on interconnected PCBs with short jumper wires).

Comment: I2C isn't really designed to sent signals over a cable, it's designed for interconnection of ICs on a circuit board.  It can be made to work over short cables, but 3 meters is going to be challenging.  Certainly lower value pull-ups will help but I wouldn't run I2C over 3m of cable.

Comment: @Majenko Ha, you beat me to it :)

Comment: I2C can be done over cables (remember [Access.bus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACCESS.bus)?), but only at much slower speeds. Fortunately, it is a synchronous protocol that can be run arbitrarily slowly.

Comment: There seems to be a chorus of responses saying I2C is not designed for transmission down a length of wire, however I don't see the reasoning for it. Clearly digital communications can occur at several magnitudes of order high speed without issue, what is it about I2C that makes it unsuitable for use remotely on a lead? Is SPI limited by the same design constraint?

Comment: All I2C devices use an open-drain driver with a pull-up resistor. In combination with the cable (or board) capacitance this severely limits how fast you can drive I2C into a long cable. Try reducing your clock speed from 400kHz to 10kHz and see if it works. There are I2C Bus Extender ICs from Texas that can work at up to 50m using twisted pair cable.

Comment: I have dropped it from 400 kHz to 200 kHz as I can see the waveforms are just about good enough to get the job done. It works for now. Interestingly I was replacing some solid core ethernet cable I'd hacked in to do the job, moving up to a wire type I assumed would be far superior. Turned out it wasn't to my surprise.

Comment: Ethernet cable is basically 100 ohm twisted pair, which requires a much lower capacitance then common jellybean control cables normally have, hence the Ethernet cable is actually better for this application. I would note that open drain with a pullup is an awful interface for pretty much anything serial, I go to some length to avoid I2C in such situations.

Comment: Is SPI any better for the job or is a full on RS-232 the only way to go? Interestingly the wave forms show the falling edge to be very sharp, but the rising edge is much slower in I2C, is this to be expected?

Comment: If you really want to use I2C on a cable, look into the related/variation electrical details used for monitor EDID information - that will likely be far more applicable than traditional PCB-local implementations.

Comment: I'm not married to I2C and know that SPI for instance is a lot faster in theory, just some peripherals don't support it and it would take additional cost/complexity to add that feature.

Comment: I'd say you need to have a close look at your assumption of one cable being "better" then another. Different cable types have different characteristics, which can make them preferable for **specific** applications. There are no general statements. You need to evaluate things on a case by case basis.

Comment: Fair comment. I suppose the 'better' choice was that it was flexible, shielded, and seemingly designed for data signals. The network cable I used because I had it spare, I wasn't actually even using the twisted pair structure to my advantage so thought it to just be effectively like long bell wire. Maybe it performs better because it is more loosely packed in the sheath, increasing the distance over which the capacitance needed to act?

Comment: The fast fall time is that the transistor that pulls the bus low has a very much lower on state resistance then the passive pull up (often a couple of k ohms) that pulls the bus back high. You can sometimes improve things by lowering the value of the pull up resistors, subject to every device on the bus being able to sink sufficient current (Not a given with SM-bus devices).  Personally I tend to favour SPI because it is actively driven in both states, sometimes sending it over a set of RS485 or LVDS electrical interfaces. It is bulk capacitance that is messing things up, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interestingly I was replacing some solid core ethernet cable I'd
>   hacked in to do the job, moving up to a wire type I assumed would be
>   far superior. Turned out it wasn't to my surprise.

Cable that has a characteristic impedance of 50 ohms tends to fall into the 100 pF per metre region and if you look at the formula for impedance above several hundreds of kHz it is approximately this: -

\$\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$

This means that the inductance is about 250 nH per metre (with a touch of hand waving). For the impedance to double to 100 ohms, something has to give and clearly the ratio L/C has to increase 4 times. This usually (and again with a bit of hand waving) means L doubles and C halves.

> I have dropped it from 400 kHz to 200 kHz as I can see the waveforms
>   are just about good enough to get the job done. It works for now.

This might easily be enough of a reason for things not to work at 400 kHz clock but become workable at 200 kHz.